Xcode Firebase "library not loaded" -- Problem running Simulator
I'm getting the following trying to run with Xcode's Simulator.  The GTMSessionFetch framework is included in the project. I'm on an M3 (Apple Silicon) MacBook.  Have had various problems trying to move code to this machine, so wondering if that's related. I simply added the Firebase frameworks to the project, added the -ObjC flag as suggested in the README.md.
What is this "file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], fat file, but missing compatible architecture ..." stuff? Other questions seemingly related suggest it is a code signing problem.
If I use Product->Build there's no problem. But running with the Simulator generates this in the console:
dyld[70392]: Library not loaded: @rpath/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher
  Referenced from: <FFFF9F7B-88DA-3D82-B1CA-419DB7B97C71> /Users/charlesjohnson/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C6358852-2298-4226-8839-F15331073CD2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F3C202F4-900E-4214-A3E1-F922CB071CA9/ASSIST for iPad.app/ASSIST for iPad
  Reason: tried: '/Users/charlesjohnson/Documents/iOS_Projects/ASSIST-main/assist_ios/DerivedData/ASSIST for iPad/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher' (file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64,arm64', need 'arm64')), '/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/Users/charlesjohnson/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C6358852-2298-4226-8839-F15331073CD2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F3C202F4-900E-4214-A3E1-F922CB071CA9/ASSIST for iPad.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher' (file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64,arm64', need 'arm64')), '/Users/charlesjohnson/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C6358852-2298-4226-8839-F15331073CD2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F3C202F4-900E-4214-A3E1-F922CB071CA9/ASSIST for iPad.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher' (file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64,arm64', need 'arm64')), '/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/Users/charlesjohnson/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C6358852-2298-4226-8839-F15331073CD2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F3C202F4-900E-4214-A3E1-F922CB071CA9/ASSIST for iPad.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher' (file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64,arm64', need 'arm64')), '/Users/charlesjohnson/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C6358852-2298-4226-8839-F15331073CD2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F3C202F4-900E-4214-A3E1-F922CB071CA9/ASSIST for iPad.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher' (file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64,arm64', need 'arm64')), '/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher' (no such file)
Logging Error: Failed to initialize logging system. Log messages may be missing. If this issue persists, try setting IDEPreferLogStreaming=YES in the active scheme actions environment variables.


I was able to get things going by removing all the frameworks and using cocoapods to install firebase instead.
